# Netbeans 10 doesn't run html pages in the browsers

Tags: netbeans, ide, netbeans-10

I have Apache netbeans 10 on Ubuntu 18.04 64 bit.

I created a simple html5/javascript project but when I run it in the notification area I have the error:

Cannot run /usr/bin/google-chrome

I have already manually installed chrome netbeans extension but nothing. I have the same problem with Firefox and the default web browser.   Which could be the problem?

Finally, when I run the binary file netbeans from shell to open Netbeans I have following warning:

WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.netbeans.core.windows.view.ui.MainWindow (jar:file:/home/nick/netbeans/platform/modules/org-netbeans-core-windows.jar!/) to field sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.awtAppClassName
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.netbeans.core.windows.view.ui.MainWindow
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

Regards

Comment: Your question contains two completely unrelated issues. Please create a new question for the second issue (opening NetBeans from shell), and remove that issue from the question above.

Comment: I also get nothing when running the project with the browser set to _Chrome with NetBeans Connector_, but everything is fine when using Chrome or Firefox instead. Can you give more details on how you created your "simple html5/javascript project"? Also, update your question with the URLs shown in the browser when you try using _Chrome_ vs. _Chrome with NetBeans Connector_.

Comment: @skomisa  I reported the warnings too because I thought that they could be useful to resolve the problem.

Comment: @skomisa I open the project from file---new project---Html5/javascript---Html5/js Application--no template.    There isn't URL in the browser bacause the browser can't be opened from Netbeans

Answer (score 0):

Recently I was having the same problem, when trying to run a **HTML5 NetBeans-Project** using **Chrome**, on **NetBeans 12.0**, **CentOS7**. *Here is what I did to be able to run the Site on Chrome* through, NetBeans ***Run's*** Command-Bar Option.

1. Select *Tools>Options*.
2. On WebBrowser List, select Chrome
3. Press Edit Button
4. The WebBrowsers Manager window will open.
5. In the Process opt., search for Chrome-App. E.g. `/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable`
6. In the Argument's Textbox, set: `--no-sandbox {URL}`
7. Press OK for each Window until all are closed.
8. On the Run's Button Bar select Chrome.
9. Press Run; then Chrome should launch your HTML5 Site.

**Note**: A warning will be prompted on Chrome due to `-no-sandbox` param.

[image]